# Running GME movement.simplecrw tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, gme

Does anyone know why my `movement.simplecrw` tool is not running?

I am looking at the impact of roads on puff adder movement. To see if individuals are crossing a road network more often or less often than their original natural path movement.

I have ArcGIS 10.3.1 and the corresponding version of GME installed on my laptop.

The problem is that the program is not reading my .csv files for my turning angle distribution or my step length distribution. This is the error I am receiving:

> The specified empirical distribution file contained no valid records:
>   C:\Users\B\Desktop\Masters\MScdata\GISdata\Frequencydistributions\Pu1_tad.csv
>
> The specified empirical distribution file contained no valid records:
>   C:\Users\B\Desktop\Masters\Mscdata\GISdata\Frequencydistributions\Pu1_sld.csv

I followed the GME.pdf that explains how to create a .csv for empirical distributions with maximum, minimum and probability values. However when I input the commands into the GME interface I am not given the drop down menu option of selecting a file path for the 'tad' and 'sld' values (which is the option for all other aspects (such as inpoint/outpoint/bnd) that have a file path).

See screenshot of the GME interface attached.

[image]

If I input the file path manually, I receive the above error.